# After capturing a video how I will remove it from PhotoLibrary?

Tags: ios, video, swift3

I am using imagePickerController to capture a video and save this video in document directory.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let pickedVideo = (info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]) as! NSURL
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedVideo.relativePath!, self, nil, nil)
    videoUrlForRemoveFromGallery.append(pickedVideo)

   let videoData = NSData(contentsOf : pickedVideo as URL)
   let ext = pickedVideo.pathExtension
   let extFull = "."+ext!
   let paths = try! FileManager.default.url(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

   let dataPathString = paths.appendingPathComponent(dateStringForFolder+extFull)
   let dataPath = dataPathString.path
   do {

       try videoData?.write(to: dataPathString)

       } catch {
                 print(error)
              }
 }
```

Now I want to remove this video from PhotoLibrary. I am doing this in another viewController. For this I am passing 
videoUrlForRemoveFromGallery array and wrote this code:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                let imageAssetToDelete = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs:  self.videoUrlForRemoveFromGallery as [URL], options: nil)
                PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(imageAssetToDelete)
            }, completionHandler: {success, error in
                print(success ? "Success" : error )
            })
```

But video doesn't remove from PhotoLibrary and I can't play this video from document directory. It says there is no such video file in document directory. But I can save and play video from document directory normally.